# Como saber que um áudio em reprodução chegou no final?

Tags: android

Então eu gostaria de saber quando que meu áudio chegou ao final da reprodução, segue meu código para startar o áudio e parar, agradeço desde já!

```
private void startRecording() {
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}
mRecorder.start();}

private void stopRecording() {
mRecorder.stop();
mRecorder.release();
mRecorder = null;

uploadAudio();
```

}

Comment: Porque você não utilizar a classe MediaPlayer para executar o áudio? Assim você consegue ter um maior controle sobre o mesmo!  Existe um evento chamado onCompletion nessa classe!

Comment: Obrigado milton, to usando o media player , tenho o onCompletion aqui, eu não sabia que ele era pra isso , para min ele era chamado assim que começava ler o arquivo e não quando acabava, enfim ..vou ver aqui.

Comment: Veja se este trecho de código te ajuda! mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //TODO
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Cara, a classe `FileObserver` te atende nessa questão, segue a [Documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html), é bem simples de usar, e quando o arquivo é fechado(finaliza a gravação), o callback `onEvent` é chamado com o parametro `CLOSE_WRITE`.

Segue o exemplo:

```
MyFileObserver fb = new MyFileObserver(mediaFile_path, FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE);
fb.startWatching();

class MyFileObserver extends FileObserver {

    public MyFileObserver (String path, int mask) {
        super(path, mask);
    }

    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        //uploadAudio();
    }
}
```

Não esqueça de chamar o método `stopWatching()`...
[Resposta original (inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418446/how-to-know-when-mediarecorder-has-finished-writing-data-to-file)